# How to Render a asp control to HTML?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I my application i need the html version of a asp page  So I began to convert the asp to the html by using the

below snippet

```
Public Function GetInnerHtml()
  Dim allTextBoxValues As String = ""
  Dim c As Control
  Dim childc As Control
  For Each c In Page.Controls
    For Each childc In c.Controls
      allTextBoxValues &= RenderControlToHtml(childc)
    Next
  Next
  Return allTextBoxValues
End Function

Public Function RenderControlToHtml(ByVal ControlToRender As Control) As String
  Try
    Dim sb As New System.Text.StringBuilder()
    Dim stWriter As New System.IO.StringWriter(sb)
    Dim htmlWriter As New System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter(stWriter)
    ControlToRender.RenderControl(htmlWriter)
    Return sb.ToString()

  Catch ex As Exception

  End Try
End Function
```

but by the above code i can get the html for label only but i am unable to generate html for the  front end code like this

```html
<div id="Drug" runat="server" > <div>
<asp:RadioButton ID="RdBtnQ2No" runat="server"  GroupName="Question2" Text="No" 
  Font-Size="12px" CssClass="scaledRadioButton" Height="20px" Width="49px"/>
```

I mean the controls with run at server are throwing an exception

saying :

```
Control 'RdBtnQ2Yes' of type 'RadioButton' must be placed inside a form tag 
with runat=server.
```

But I have placed every control in the `<form runat="server">` tag.

Comment: Try and render the Form itself with all child controls.

Comment: @pln Cam u elaborate

Comment: My thoughts was to slap an ID on the form runat tag and render the whole thing but I see there may be more to this error. [Perhaps try this suggestion](http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?165546-Using-RenderControl-with-a-TextBox).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="plainHtml.aspx.vb" EnableEventValidation="false" Inherits="Default3" %>
```

i had added "EnableEventValidation="false" in .aspx page it is working well now